# Typescript : Error using vue-check-view library

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I success declare the js plugin with *.d.ts, but after I do .use(checkView), my view is blank, did this library [vue-check-view](https://github.com/vtimofeev/vue-check-view) support on Typescript?

error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$isServer' of undefined

main.ts file

```
import checkView from 'vue-check-view'
....
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(checkView).component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon).mount('#app')
```

*.d.ts file

```
declare module "vue-check-view"; any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try npm package update

```
npm install
```

Comment: still blank, I think this library did not support Typescript

Comment: @RickoTiaka You need to compile typescript files and then include transpiled js files in the source code. You can use webpack or babel etc to do the compilation.